# Update programmatically BBOX of WMS Geoserver layer

Tags: geoserver, geoserver-rest-api, bbox

I create programmatically a layer in PostGIS and Geoserver. I give the option to the user to choose the geometry and the attributes and then I create the table in PostGIS and add it in an **existing** store in Geoserver.

The layer, as initialized, it gets a global Bounding Box.
Then the user is able to add specific data. What I want is to be able to recalculate the Bounding Box depending on the data, so when I show the map on Leaflet to show only the selected area.
I need to do that programmatically using the Rest API.

I haven't found anything like this for single layers (not layergroups) and also for WMS layers.

Does anyone has any experience on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `PUT` an updated `FeatureType` document with the new bounding box set in it.

So your workflow is something like:

```
 curl -v -u admin:geoserver -H 'Accept: text/xml' \
   -XGET http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/workspaces/topp/datastores/states_shapefile/featuretypes/states.xml
```

Then edit the Bounding box to your new value and delete the lat/lon bounding box and `PUT` it back:

```
 curl -v -u admin:geoserver -H 'Accept: text/xml' -H 'Content-type: text/xml' \
   -XPUT http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/workspaces/topp/datastores/states_shapefile/featuretypes/states.xml \
   -d @states.xml
```

GeoServer will automatically recalculate the lat/lon bounding box for you. There is also a [recalculate parameter](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/rest/api/featuretypes.html#recalculate) you can use to force the recalculation of the bounding boxes if you prefer but this may be much slower if you have a large table.

Comment: Ok. Thank you. So after getting the XML I need to parse it and retrieve the latLonBoundingBox element. I guess using regex to get the element would be the way to go. Or do you have another suggestion?

Comment: I would use an XML parser and select the element I need, could also do the whole thing in json if you are stuck in a browser.

Answer (score 1):

You'll find the parameter on the feature type resource:
http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/rest/api/featuretypes.html#recalculate